# Python 3.6 - Literal string interpolation using JSON

Tags: python, python-3.6, string-interpolation

I am trying to read a JSON file, which includes Python variables, which should be shown as the value of the variable and not as the variable itself.

```
with open('path_to_file.json') as f:
           my_json = json.load(f)

json_variable = my_json['text']

# The example text in the json file is:
# Hello, I want to be there in {defined_days} days

defined_days = 3

# What I tried, but doesn't work
interpolated_text = f'{json_variable}'

# Output of interpolated_text:
# Hello, I want to be there in {defined_days} days
```

It shows the string from the json file, but **defined_days** will not be replaced with the number **3**.

Comment: Try `json_variable.format(defined_days=defined_days)`, that's not how f-strings work.

Comment: Please share some sample input and output, see [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your format string is in a variable, you'll need to use the `format` method instead of f-strings

```
json_variable = 'Hello, I want to be there in {defined_days} days'

defined_days = 3

interpolated_text = json_variable.format(**locals())

print(interpolated_text)
```

Output:

```
Hello, I want to be there in 3 days
```

Comment: I don't know what `**locals() ` exactly mean in Python (especially the two asterisk), but it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `locals()` returns a `dictionary` of all the local variables available at the time of calling & their values. The `**` is used for unrolling that dictionary into key-value pairs for the call to `format`. One of those key-value pairs will be `defined_days=3`. That wwill be picked up by the formatting string to get the result you want. This is more useful when you have a lot of variables you want to pass to `format` - you don't have to pass each of those manually

Comment: That's the best explanation I've ever read about everything. Thanks a lot :)